# Pymongo agregation result in the hole collection

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to join two collection with pymongo and I receive a wired result. The collection are not joining. In the result there are all documents from products, not only that ones that match the expiration of the document from the discount collection.

Recived result:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5f0ebf8b967b140007686e46'), 'expiration_days': 5, 'discount': 50, 'results': [{'_id': ObjectId('5f0ebfdf967b140007686e4b'), 'product_name': 'egg', 'expiration': 5}, {'_id': ObjectId('5f0ebff7967b140007686e4d'), 'product_name': 'milk', 'expiration': 5}, {'_id': ObjectId('5f0ec014967b140007686e4f'), 'product_name': 'meat', 'expiration': 10}, {'_id': ObjectId('5f0ec04f967b140007686e51'), 'product_name': 'cucumber', 'expiration': 10}]}
```

The Collections are:

Discount collection:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f0ebf8b967b140007686e46"},"expiration_days":5,"discount":50}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f0ebfa3967b140007686e48"},"expiration_days":10,"discount":20}
```

Products collection:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f0ebfdf967b140007686e4b"},"product_name":"egg","expiration":5}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f0ebff7967b140007686e4d"},"product_name":"milk","expiration":5}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f0ec014967b140007686e4f"},"product_name":"meat","expiration":10}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f0ec04f967b140007686e51"},"product_name":"cucumber","expiration":10}
```

Agregation query:

```
collection.aggregate([ {'$lookup' : {'from': 'products','localField': 'expiration','foreignField': 'expiration_days','as': 'results' }}])
```

Comment: It looks like you have `localField` and `foreignField` reversed.

Comment: Yes, this fixed it, thanks. It is confusing, because the local field of the products colection is "expiration"

Comment: The collection you are looking up from is the foreign collection, so it should contain the foreignField.   If localField doesn't exist in the source document, and foreignField doesn't exist in the `from` collection, the lookup will match everything.